# Vector Representation unit vectors

Tags: vectors

So if I have like the vector (2,3) what does this really mean? Because I watched a 3brown1blue video and in it he said a way to represent vectors is that the 2 and 3 are just scalars for the unit/basis vectors (i and j) so it can also just be 2i + 3j, now my question is when I write (2,3) does this mean like going to the right 2 in the x axis and up 3 in the y axis or does it mean 2i + 3j?
He even says "but for now right I just want you to appreciate the fact that anytime we describe vectors numerically it depends on an implicit choice of what basis vectors we're using" I always thought that (3,1) means I'm going to the right 3 and up 1 but according to him that's not the case and it depends on what basis vectors we're using

Answer (score 1):

Vectors are not necessarily little arrows.  Vectors can represent any objects that have the algebraic properties of vectors (vector addition and scalar multiplication).  I know, that sounds vague.

I could choose a vector to represent a polynomial.

For example, I can define $(a,b,c) = ax^2 + bx + c$ and if I add two ordered triples that are defined this way using the basic vector addition rules I get the same result as if I added the equivalent polynomials together.  Same for scalar multiplication.

The basis of this vector space, is $\{x^2, x, 1\}$

I could also use a vector to represent a function.  My basis might be $\{f(1), f(2), f(3)\}$ and the vector  $(1,4,9)$ would be a function that goes through the points $(1,1), (2,4), (3,9)$

Products of vectors (e.g. dot product, cross product, wedge product) are specific to the vector space you are representing.

However, in the context of vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ you can think of them as little arrows, and in the canonical basis the vector $(2,3)$ would be an arrow that points to the point 2 to the right and up 3.

And, in $\mathbb R^2$ we can work in a non-standard basis.

Comment: Okay thank you but so in R2 I can think of it as just an arrow that points to the point 2 to the right and up 3 but what about that part I said where I saw a video about a guy saying  "but for now right I just want you to appreciate the fact that anytime we describe vectors numerically it depends on an implicit choice of what basis vectors we're using" if I chose different basis vectors would this mean something else? I thought of these numbers as just numbers and not the scales at which we change the basis vectors

Comment: Until you develop your intuition with working with vectors, it is fine to think that all vectors are in some sort of standard basis.  But, as you become more comfortable with linear transformations, it becomes apparent why a change of basis will simplify the problem.  Once you realize that the choice of basis is arbitrary, vector spaces become simultaneously more abstract and more powerful.

Comment: One example where it might make sense to change bases in $\mathbb R^2$ is the classic physics problem of an object on an inclined plane.  While we can continue to work with the standard horizontal and vertical basis, this problem can be simplified if we transition to basis vectors parallel to the plane and perpendicular to the plane.